# Using *ngFor to loop through an array and *ngIf to select which elements from the array to list

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use `*ngFor` to loop through an array of objects. I realized I couldn't use `*ngFor` and an `*ngIf` on the same element, it would return an error. Instead, I tried to stick my `*ngIf` on the contents of the list item. But now, I'm getting a bunch of empty list items and they're being created and displayed on my view page.

I don't want to stick the `*ngFor` on my `<ul>` element because then it will create a bunch of `<ul>` elements with a single list item within each.

I'm hoping one of you will have another method of implementing this.

```
// AppComponent
// contacts: Contact[];  // An array of `Contact` Objects

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#contact of contacts">
    <contact-detail *ngIf="checkList(contact) == true" [contact]="contact"></contact-detail>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and...

```
// ContactDetailComponent
<img />
<span>{{contact.name}}</span>
<span>{{contact.email}}</span>
```

What is happening:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <!--template bindings={}-->  // ngIf conditional returned true
    <img />
    <span>Name1</span>
    <span>Email1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <!--template bindings={}-->   // ngIf conditional returned false
  </li>
  <li>
    <!--template bindings={}-->  // false
  </li>
  <li>
    <!--template bindings={}-->  // true
    <img />
    <span>Name1</span>
    <span>Email1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Material Design Lite, so all these elements will have some css properties. Empty `<li>` just return an empty space of a certain height.

Also, if other information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: You should be able to use ngFor with ngIf in [beta.8](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6304)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realized I'm using beta.6 :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both *ngFor and *ngIf (with asterisk) are [structural directives](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#) and they generate `<template>` tag:

> Structural directives, like ngIf, do their magic by using the HTML 5 template tag.

You can get functionality you want with this syntax:

```
<ul>
  <template ngFor #contact [ngForOf]="contacts">
    <li *ngIf="checkList(contact) == true" >
      <contact-detail [contact]="contact"></contact-detail>
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

example: http://plnkr.co/edit/JeDbVi4pXrzJ5SRIonjH?p=preview

Comment: Great! This worked like a charm. Thanks for the great answer and also providing resources :)

Comment: Great answer, I had the same issue and this pointed me in the right direction. Btw "#contact" didn't work for me, "let-contact" did.

Comment: What if I needed to display an `index` which should always be in order? When I use `index`, it skips indices for the items for which `ngIf` returned `false`.

Answer (score -1):

Sasxa's answer didn't work for me at 2022. You can use ng-template instead of template to get the same result.

```
<ul>
    <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="calcService.myDataArray">
        <li *ngIf="item.esTarifa === true">
            {{item.id}}
        </li>
    </ng-template>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi José Sánchez to make your answer clear for users you need to explain it in detail without error

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Navruzbek. I have edited my answer and I hope that is more clear now.