# Update only selected array item in *ngFor array Angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, frontend

I have an *ngFor loop to display libraries. When you click on a library, categories of that library appear beneath in a tree-like structure. The categories are also being displayed with an *ngFor loop. When I have one library expanded and click on another one, the categories in BOTH libraries are updating to the categories in the library that was just clicked. The functionality I am looking for is to only update the selected library categories and leave the others alone. There is a post here that seems to be close to my problem but I couldn't get it to work.

[Using *ngFor to loop through an array and *ngIf to select which elements from the array to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786054/using-ngfor-to-loop-through-an-array-and-ngif-to-select-which-elements-from-th)

Here is my code:

library.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let messageLibrary of onHoldMessageLibraryService.data"  class="library mgn-top10 ft-size14">          
    <a (click)="onHoldMessageLibraryService.getSelectedMessageLibrary(messageLibrary)"><i class="fa fa-folder-o mgn-right10" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{messageLibrary.Name}}</a>
    <library-category *ngIf="messageLibrary.treeIsExpanded" (displayMessagesFromSelectedCategory)="getOnHoldMessages()"></library-category>
</div>
```

library.service

```
public treeIsExpanded: boolean;
public selectMessages: boolean;
public data: TreeData[];
public selectedName: string;
public selectedValue: number;


public getSelectedMessageLibrary(messageLibrary): void {
     this.selectedMessagesLibrary = messageLibrary;
     this.selectedMessagesLibrary.treeIsExpanded = !this.selectedMessagesLibrary.treeIsExpanded;
   }



public dummyData(): void {
    let myTree: TreeData[] = new Array();
    myTree.push(
    {
      Name: 'Banking Library',
      Id: 1,
      Category: [{
        Name: 'Credit Cards',
        Id: 11,
        Category: null
      }]
     },
    {
      Name: 'Automobile Library',
      Id: 2,
      Category: [{
        Name: 'Cars',
        Id: 12,
        Category: null
      }]
     },
    {
      Name: 'Coffee Library',
      Id: 3,
      Category: [{
        Name: 'Americano',
        Id: 13,
        Category: null
      }]
     }
    )

    this.data = myTree;

   }
```

library-category.component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let category of onHoldMessageLibraryService.selectedMessagesLibrary.Category">
    <li><i class="fa fa-folder-o mgn-right10" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{category.Name}}</li>
</ul>
```

tree-data.ts

```
export class TreeData {
Name: string;
Id: number;
Category: TreeData[];
```

}

Comment: update your post with `messageLibrarySelected()` method

Comment: That method just displays the selected library in the view. It isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: that is the place where the issue might be. You post has **When you click on a library,** what does this mean?

Comment: In the library.component.html file, I'm referring to the first anchor tag when I say "click on a library". {{messageLibrary.Name}} displays the library name, I apologize for the confusion. The messageLibrarySelected() method really doesn't have to do with my issue. This method just emits a method to the parent component and switches some variables to true to display different components. This is separate from the tree view that my question is about. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: are you available in team viewer. will work and fix

Answer (score 0):

```
public getSelectedMessageLibrary(messageLibrary): void {
     this.selectedMessagesLibrary = messageLibrary; 
     this.selectedMessagesLibrary.treeIsExpanded = !this.selectedMessagesLibrary.treeIsExpanded; //this line is not giving desired result
   }
```

to be replaced with

```
public getSelectedMessageLibrary(messageLibrary): void {
     messageLibrary.treeIsExpanded = !messageLibrary.treeIsExpanded;
   }
```

And it will be good if you use trackBy with NgFor

Comment: Can you give more detail on how to use trackBy? I can't get your suggestion to work.

Comment: trackBy function  helps Angular keep track of items in the list so that it can detect which items have been added or removed and improve performance.
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/directives/ng_for_directive.html